# Where is angular2-polyfills now that non-beta Angular 2 is packaged as @angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Now that Angular2 is out of beta (2.0.0-RC.0 and RC.1 came out yesterday/May 3, 2016), all of Angular 2 is packaged for use with NPM under the new @angular namespace.  A lot of packages have been moved and must be individually installed now, as you can see in the [Angular2 CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc1-2016-05-03).

But one thing that the CHANGELOG doesn't address is how to find the `angular2-polyfills` bundle that was available previously.

My beta code called this in one of its TypeScript files:

```
import 'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills';
```

What do I need to do now to get that same functionality with the new package layout?

Here is the `ventdor.ts` file that used to import the polyfills so that it could be included by webpack:

```
require('./css/bootstrap.css');
require('./css/main.css');

import 'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills'; // THIS NO LONGER WORKS

require('./lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.js');
```

The lack of the polyfills causes errors like the following when I build my application with webpack:

```
ERROR in /Users/mfo/Projects/PennMutual/angular2-oauth2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts
(28,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in /Users/mfo/Projects/PennMutual/angular2-oauth2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts
(4,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/mfo/Projects/PennMutual/angular2-oauth2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts
(5,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Thierry Templier said in his answer, the issue is that `zone.js` and `reflect-metadata` have to be brought in now that the `angular2-polyfills.js` bundle is no longer available.

To get the functionality back, you need to import them directly instead of relying on the old polyfills code.

```
//import 'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills'; // no longer available
import 'reflect-metadata';
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone'); // for development only - not needed for prod deployment
```

The `reflect-metadata` package already has built-in typings for TypeScript, so you can use `import`.  Zone.js does not, however, so you need to rely on `require()` to get webpack to pick it up and include it in your bundles.

Of course you also need to have reflect and zone in your `package.json` dependencies section (mine are listed at the end, below):

```
{
  "name": "angular2-bootstrap4-oauth2-ohmy",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "description": "A skeleton Angular2, Bootstrap 4, OAuth2 application using webpack (oh my!)",
  "repository": "https://github.com/michaeloryl/angular2-bootstrap4-oauth2-webpack.git",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.11.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "traceur": "0.0.93",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
}
```

Once that is done, you should have a working application again (assuming you took care of the other issues involved in moving from Angular2 beta to the RC (release candidate) code.

This code is a sample from my [angular2-bootstrap4-oauth2-webpack](https://github.com/michaeloryl/angular2-bootstrap4-oauth2-webpack) project on Github.

Answer (score 6):

There is no more `angular2-polyfills.js` file. You need to include explicitly ZoneJS and Reflect Metadata libraries (FYI angular2-polyfill contained these two libraries) So you need to include the following:

```
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
```

Comment: At least in the webpack world, there's more to it than this.  I can't just put it in index.html like that because those files are not available there.  Webpack is putting it all together into just a few files, in this particular case one called vendor.js.  Files only get included by being imported into one of the top level files, or being imported into a file that is intern imported into a top level file (minor simplification of it).

Comment: Yes, you're right regarding webpack. I think that you need to import the zonejs and reflect-metadata dependencies instead of angular2-polyfill. Sorry I don't really know how to configure webpack...

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this issue with rc.5 and solved it by importing zone like so:

```
// import 'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills'; // old
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; 
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
```